# Using and Creating helper in Asp.net MVC4 Web Application

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-roles, razor-declarative-helpers

I am using the Asp.net mvc4 WebRole, and I found this is a Web Application , Not a Web Site.
after reading [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site), I knew how to add customer Helper function in Asp.MVC4.  In Web Site Appliction I can add a cshtml file in app_code folder like below so that I can use my custom helper method in another cshtml.

```
  @helper  HotDeployButton(string value, string url , bool enable= true){

      string enablestr = string.Empty;
      if (!enable)
      {
          enablestr = "disabled=\"disabled\"";
      }

      <input type="button"  name="@value" value="@value" onclick=" window.location.href='@url'" class="mobile-button"  @enablestr />
  }

  @helper Img(string picName, string alt ){

      string root = "/content/themes/default/images/";
      string imgurl = root + picName;

      <img  alt="@alt" src="@imgurl" title="@alt" />

  }
```

In Another cshtml shown below will use `HotDeployButton` method.

```
<div class="bottom-div">
            @Html.Hidden("hdSelMinorPackId", "")
            <!--Html.Hidden("randomId", (object)ViewBag.RandomId)-->
            <input type="submit" name="ExcuteDeploy" id="ExcuteDeploy" value="Deploy" onclick="return validateVersion();"
                class="mobile-button" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            @Helpers.HotDeployButton("Back", Url.Action("Index"))
        </div>
```

But in Asp.net Web Application there is no App_code Folder in project. I don't know how to make it in a Web Application . please help me .Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The directory is not created with the default Web Application project template so you just need to create the `App_Code` folder by hand and it should work (right click on the project -> Add -> New Folder).

If you've done it right it will have a special icon:

[image]

By the way this is the first step in your [linked tutorial:](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/creating-and-using-a-helper-in-an-aspnet-web-pages-site)

> Creating a Helper
>
> This procedure shows you how to create the helper that creates the
>   note, as just described. This is a simple example, but the custom
>   helper can include any markup and ASP.NET code that you need.
>
> 1. **In the root folder of the website, create a folder named App_Code.** This is a reserved folder name in ASP.NET where you can put code for
>      components like helpers.